# How call WCF function from Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, wcf, function

that's the problem: there is WCF - http://www.mathforyou.net/IOSService.svc and function - iOSTest.

The function returns a short message with the current time on the server (it has no arguments).

Question - how do I call this function from Objective-C

Sorry for my English, it's Google Translate)))

Comment: Objective-C running on the same (Windows) machine?

Comment: @trojanfoe What do you mean?

Comment: And what sort of Objective-C runtime are you using?

Comment: @trojanfoe In the objective-c I do not do anything, because I want to learn to call the WCF function. This is my question - how do I do this?

Comment: Well you could try using GNUstep I guess: http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html

Comment: @trojanfoe I do not understand - what's the windose? I want my iOS application to receive a response from the server through the WCF feature, which I do not have access

Comment: Oh I see; I asked you if you were running Objective-C on a Windows machine, and as you didn't say "no" I assumed you were.  It's a problem in translation I guess.